# Converting and object to a generic base interface

Tags: c#

Here is the setup...

```
public class MyBase { }

public abstract class CommandBase : MyBase { }

public class MyCommand : CommandBase { }

public interface ICommandHandler { }

public interface ICommandHandler<in T> : ICommandHandler where T : CommandBase
{
    IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(T item);
}

public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand> { }
```

I have an `object` (lets call it `thing`) that I know is a `MyCommandHandler`, and I want to cast it to `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>`.  Cant seem to do it.  `thing as ICommandHandler<CommandBase>` returns null.  Any ideas?

Using .NET 4.6, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast would work if `ICommandHandler` was covariant, not contravariant.

Imagine what would happen if such a cast was allowed. Let's say we have another class inheriting from `CommandBase`

```
public class MyOtherCommand : CommandBase { }
```

Now we could do

```
ICommandHandler<CommandBase> handler = new MyCommandHandler();
handler.Handle(new MyOtherCommand());
```

And we have a problem, because `MyCommandHandler.Handle` expects a `MyCommand` parameter, not `MyOtherCommand`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast it into an `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>` because `MyCommandHandler` doesn't implement `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>`, it implements `ICommandHandler<MyCommand>`. You can't guarantee that you *can* cast it; in fact, my compiler (VS2015 with .NET 4.6) complains about a 'suspicious cast', and I would be surprised if yours didn't as well.

If you change `MyCommandHandler` to implement `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>` instead, you're fine. In fact, then you can cast it to `ICommandHandler<MyCommand>` too, if you feel the need.

try the code below in a console app, and stick a breakpoint in `Main`. You'll see that you get back not-null objects from the casts from z, but not from a.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new MyCommandHandler();
        var z = new MyBaseCommandHandler();
        var b = a as ICommandHandler<CommandBase>;
        var y = z as ICommandHandler<CommandBase>;
        var x = z as ICommandHandler<MyCommand>;
    }
}

public class MyBase { }

public abstract class CommandBase : MyBase { }

public class MyCommand : CommandBase { }

public interface ICommandHandler { }

public interface ICommandHandler<in T> : ICommandHandler where T : CommandBase
{
    IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(T item);
}

public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand>
{
    public IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(MyCommand item)
    {
        return new List<EventBase>();
    }
}

public class MyBaseCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CommandBase>
{
    public IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(CommandBase item)
    {
        return new List<EventBase>();
    }
}

public class EventBase
{ }
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can loosen up the restriction on the ICommandHandler to look like this

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in T> : ICommandHandler
```

and then this works :

```
        MyCommandHandler c = new MyCommandHandler();
        ICommandHandler<MyCommand> ch = c as ICommandHandler<MyCommand>;
```